# How to upload HTMLCanvasElement to Firebase storage (React)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, image, file-upload, html5-canvas

I'm using a library called react-avatar-editor to crop images upload by a user before uploading it to firebase storage.
After cropping the original image, a HTMLCanvasElement is returned I think.
I then call .toDataURL() and then try and upload that to firebase storage.

But this appears in firebase storage as type: application/octet-stream and I can't see the image.

Does anyone know the process of uploading the cropped image (HTMLCanvasElement) to firebase storage?

Comment: `.toDataURL()` <-- _please don't_ - use `toBlob` instead: it's faster, it's asynchronous, it's efficient, etc. `data:` URIs should not be used for large binaries like raster images.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your answer, using toBlob solved the issue!